# How can I get more colors in emacs vc-diff?

Tags: emacs, colors, version-control, emacs23

I would like to have vc-diff colorize the output so that added lines are in one color and deleted ones in another. Using Emacs 23.1 and putty/xterm-256color (list-colors-display shows 256 colors and color themes and such works as expected).

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [`diff-mode-.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/diff-mode-.el) provides more colors.

You can customize the colors by either [customizing the faces](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingFaces) `diff-indicator-removed` and `diff-indicator-added`, or changing the variables `diff-indicator-removed-face` and `diff-indicator-added-face` to be faces whose colors/properties you like.  There are also `changed` varieties of the face and variable.

Other packages for enhancing `diff-mode` can be found [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiffEnhancements).

Comment: Weird name and the default settings weren't the best but a good start. Thank you!

Comment: Yah, I don't like the default colors of that package.

Answer (score 16):

To just modify the colors of the added and removed lines:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(diff-added ((t (:foreground "Green"))) 'now)
 '(diff-removed ((t (:foreground "Red"))) 'now)
 )
```

See Treys answer for a more complete customization.

Comment: +1 I totally missed the default coloring options.  `diff-mode-` has some flair, but this totally works.